# understanding issue - System.out.println

Tags: java, println, system.out

I'm new to programming and started out with Java today. I'm reading the online version of 'Introduction to programming in Java' by Robert Sedgewick and Kevin Wayne and using the DrJava editor.

There is a particular exercise that left me wondering:

`Modify UseArgument.java to make a program UseThree.java that takes three names and prints out a proper sentence with the names in the reverse of the order given, so that for example, "java UseThree Alice Bob Carol" gives "Hi Carol, Bob, and Alice.".`

My result looks like this:

```
    public class UseThree {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Hi, ");
        System.out.print(args[2]);
        System.out.print(", ");
        System.out.print(args[1]);
        System.out.print(", and ");
        System.out.print(args[0]);
        System.out.println(".");
    }
}
```

Now, when I type `java UseThree Alice Bob Carol` it says `Hi, Carol, Bob, and Alice.`

But I thought that `System.out.println` prints in a new line.

Shouldn't the result be like this?

`Hi, Carol, Bob and Alice

.`

I hope you can shed some light on the topic for me, I want to get things right from the beginning. Thank you in advance.

Greetings from Germany,

Kadir

Comment: To make your further learning much easier, here's how you find answer to similar questions: 1) Enter "java 6 api system" in google. Navigate to first link with api on "class System". 2) Find `out` field (at the top), click on it's type "PrintStream". 3) Find `println(String x)` method. Read it's description.

Comment: I will make use of that, thank you.

Comment: You are welcome. Java api is documented very nicely, so you can learn a lot by simply reading descriptions of various classes. For example try reading about String: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Answer (score 4):

New line is printed after, not before the text that you pass to `println`.

Comment: Wow, that was quick. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Kadir There's a reason why questions like this are called "speed typing contests" :)  Welcome to the site!

Comment: Thank you, this site is great! I'm so lucky to have found it :)